# How to append/extend multiple elements into an Array?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, pandas

I'm having issues trying to input headers into my array, I cannot append the array with headers of the values within the array. I've also attempted to use .extend, but it's also giving me issues.

```
mylist = []

for i in jsonResponse['M']:
     if i['x'] == 'n':
          x = ((i['x']))
          y = ((i['x']['y']))
          z = ((i['x']['z']))

          mylist.append([x,y,z])

          import pandas as pd

          #panda related stuff
          df0 = pd.DataFrame(data=mylist)
          df0.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=True, index=False)
```

I'm trying to have:

```
mylist.append('Header1': [x],['Header2': [y],['Header3': [z])
```

I've tried using the `.extend` as I would think it's the most appropriate, but it's giving me error.

The purpose of this is when I write the data to excel, it would be most ideal to have a header. The problem stems from opening the array from the very beginning above the JSON pull, I think i have to open the array, because it's a means to allocate memory to store the values.

I was thinking as a solution would be to create an array for value from the JSON pull meaning:

```
x = []
y = []
z = []
for i in jsonResponse['M']:
     if i['x'] == 'n':
          x = ((i['x']))
          y = ((i['x']['y']))
          z = ((i['x']['z']))

          x.append('header1':[x])
          y.append('header2':[y])
          z.append('header3':[z])
```

But I don't know if that's going to work; I really don't want to go through that as it's a bit labor intensive, because I have a lot of json objects.

I'm new to Python and never wrote anything in a language before. I'm trying, I've spent most my time copying script from the documentation and other users attempting to parse together a workable code and at the same time trying to understand what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (or dict) in Python.

A `dict` allows you to create mappings like this:

```
{'name': 'John', 'age': 30}
```

---

So, now all you have to do is you need to create a `dict` inside your for loop and then append that `dict` to `mylist`.

```
for i in jsonResponse['M']:
    ...
    mylist.append({'Header1': x, 'Header2': y, 'Header3': z})
```

Comment: Awesome, this really worked, I see my problem, I did try this at first, but it didn't work that's because i was implementing it like this:    mylist.append('header1':[x],'header2':[y],'header3':[z])  So my question, the brackets dictates the list is an array(list) or dictionary?

Comment: @UsualSuspect7 Yes, most of the times it depends on the brackets. `tuple - (1, 2, 3)`, `list - [1, 2, 3]`, `dict - {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`. There's another data type in Python called a `set`. It has the curly brackets similar to a `dict` but it doesn't have the mapping -  `set - {1, 2, 3}`.